# MassTransit 3.0.1 (prerelease) with RabbitMQ fails to process messages using same configuration/setup as 2.9.9

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Here's the MT 2.9.9 version that works:

```
public sealed class DiagnosticConsumer : Consumes<DiagnosticMessage>.All
{
    public void Consume(DiagnosticMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got {0} with timestamp {1}", message.Message, message.Timestamp);
    }
}
```

Bus setup:

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    sbc.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/notifications/tests"),
        c =>
        {
            c.SetUsername("test_user");
            c.SetPassword("testuser123");
        }));
    sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/notifications/tests");
    sbc.Subscribe(s =>
                  {
                      s.Consumer<DiagnosticConsumer>();
                  });
});


using (bus)
{
    bus.Publish(new DiagnosticMessage { Message = "Test msg", Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now });
    Console.WriteLine("Published!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

That works as expected and when using RabbitMQ Management I can see that the following:
[image: RabbitMQ charts for MT 2.9.9]

Now, using MT 3.0.1-alpha along with MassTransit.RabbitMQ 3.0.1-alpha and the following setup:

```
public sealed class DiagnosticConsumer : IConsumer<DiagnosticMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DiagnosticMessage> context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got message: {0}", context.Message);
    }
}
```

Bus configuration:

```
public static async Task RunQueue()
{
    var bus = Bus.Factory
                 .CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
                 {
                     var host =
                         c.Host(
                             new Uri(
                                 "rabbitmq://localhost/notifications"),
                             conf =>
                             {
                                 conf.Username("test_user");
                                 conf.Password("testuser123");
                             });
                     c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "tests", conf =>
                     {
                         conf.Consumer<DiagnosticConsumer>();
                     });
                 });

    using (var handle = await bus.Start())
    {
        await bus.Publish(new DiagnosticMessage{ Message = "Pinging!", Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now});
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting to finish...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        await handle.Stop();
    }
}
```

In this scenario, nothing really happens, consumer never gets the message and the management console also tells a different story:
[image: RabbitMQ charts for MT 3.0.1-alpha]

In both cases, it's the exact same queue and setup, which in itself is really simple. Is there anything wrong on my side that I would have to fix to use latest version of MassTransit, or is it just alpha-version bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the second report of such a problem, can you check the bindings of the message type to the queue? I believe the alpha has an issue where the published message types are not bound to the queue properly by default. Another user reported the same thing last week, it's on my list to investigate with a clean virtual host.

Since `Send` works, and `Publish` doesn't, that's likely the issue.

Comment: That's it! The exchange for the notification class was not bound to any queue, once I bound it using the management console, `Publish` started working. Why doesn't it affect `ISendEndpoint.Send`?

Comment: Because ```Send``` does an explicit send to an exchange (which in your case was the exchange bound to the queue), versus publish which sends to the type-based exchange for the message type (which wasn't bound in your example).

Comment: FYI, 3.0.2-alpha fixes the binding omission from the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I found a half-answer to my own question.

Apparently publishing works if it's done via `ISendEndpoint`:

```
var address = new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/notifications/tests");
var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(address);
await endpoint.Send(new DiagnosticMessage{ Message = "Pinging!", Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now});
```

In this case, message is delivered successfully.

That being said, I'm not sure what the point of `Publish` is in its current form or why messages pushed through it are not delivered, especially inside the consumer when using `ConsumeContext<>`. It also seems to cause problems if you want to schedule messages, since they're being scheduled using `Publish`.

Until the behavior is changed or someone else has a better answer as to *why* all this happens, I guess I found the solution to my immediate problem.

#### [Edit]

As Chris Patterson noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28946165/1180426), the exchange type for the message was not bound to the queue. Setting that up manually via the management console got `Publish` to work.

Comment: And I found the bug in the branch and fixed it, but haven't released a new alpha version yet. Soon.